# Texts in the style of the Little Schemer

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

*The Little Schemer* and books like it have a two column format with very simple questions on one side and answers on the other. The answers are short and direct and tend to build on previous questions. I've found them (in particular *the Reasoned Schemer*) to be very helpful for showing you your misunderstandings and keeping you honest.

I found a picture containing an excerpt of one page of *The Little Schemer*, but I'm not sure about its copyright status so I'll make up some example questions to illustrate the style using a hypothetical programming language.

```
       What is 2 + 2?          |               4
                               |
                               |
       What is 2 + 2.0?        |             4.0
                               |
                               |
       Why does it look        |      Because 2 is an integer and
       different?              |      2.0 is a floating point number
                               |      and their sum is a floating point
                               |      number.
```

Are there books, texts online, &c in this style covering math topics?